# Writing a proper timestamp for string date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to obtain NSDate from the given string:

```
NSString* dateString = @"March 23 04:00 AM";
NSDateFormatter* firstDateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[firstDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMММ dd h:mm a"];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[firstDateFormatter setLocale:locale];
NSDate* date = [firstDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date:%@", date);
```

The date I am getting is null where I've made a mistake?

Comment: I'd say you've made the (far too common) mistake of not reading the documentation that Apple provide for the iOS SDK.

Comment: @NickBull The question was actually a bit tricky due to difference between MMMM and LLLL, so I'm happy that it found it place on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with the date format you set. According to apple

> The format string uses the format patterns from the [Unicode Technical
>   Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

In your case you need to use stand-alone version of month that is `LLLL` not `MMMM`.
If you change this line, your code will work just fine

```
[firstDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"LLLL dd hh:mm a"];
```

The standard explains the standalone version as follow:

> The most important distinction to make between format and stand-alone
>   forms is a grammatical distinction, for languages that require it. For
>   example, many languages require that a month name without an
>   associated day number be in the basic nominative form, while a month
>   name with an associated day number should be in a different
>   grammatical form: genitive, partitive, etc. Another common type of
>   distinction between format and stand-alone involves capitalization;
>   however, this can be controlled separately and more precisely using
>   the  element as described in Section 5.19
>   ContextTransform Elements.

Btw. Read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) it contains a lot of info along with better ways of initializing the dateformatter.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! You even answered my not-asked question (what is stand-alone for example :))

Comment: Would you be so kind to answer why I'm getting the date = 1970-03-23 01:00:00 +0000 though when I convert it to string using another formatter it appears to be ok:
at 4:00 AM, March 23. I mean - what is going on with hours?

Comment: @Stas, Thx, I was surprised seeing the "stand-alone", so I've though that putting a bit of rationale will be good :)

Comment: It uses your timezone to parse the date, I'm getting this: 1970-03-23 03:00:00 +0000, As I'm in gmt+1 you are probably in gmt - 3. Just use your time zone to print the date out and it should be ok

Answer (score 0):

Use `hh` for two-digit hours:

```
[firstDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMММ dd hh:mm a"];
```